# How do I inject dependency into datalayer dll?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a project with the following structure

WebUI (mvc project)
Domain (DLL - Contains models)
Domain Interfaces (DLL)
Data Access Layer (DLL)

Now I have the following class in the data access layer

```
public class DataService
{
  public List<IClient> GetClients()
  {

  }
}
```

I assume that creating a concrete implementation of Client is not a good idea (Or is it)? Therefore what is the best way to inject this into the GetClients() Method?

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with a data layer you usually have [Data Transfer Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978717.aspx) (DTOs) which would be concrete but have no logic in them. Because there is no logic there is no need to inject dependencies in to a `Client` object so there is no need to have them created by DI.